# Which header file defines Serial.begin?

Tags: netbeans, arduino, header-files, serial-communication

I'm working on a small Arduino project. I need to know where the Serial functions like `Serial.begin` and `Serial.read` are defined. My IDE is complaining that these functions are undefined, so I want to point my IDE to the headers to get code assistance working properly (Netbeans).

Which header file defines these functions? Or how can I search to find them?

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.begin()` is defined in the `setup()` function.
You have to give the baud rate in the `Serial.begin()` function.
For example, `Serial.begin(9600`)`.

`Serial.read()` can be defined anywhere in your `loop()` function. 
It does not need to be defined if you used `Serial.begin()` in the setup() function already.

Hope that solves your problem :)

For more info check out the example on [this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read) website

Comment: Thanks but I think I'm being misunderstood here. I know how to use the `Serial.begin` function. But I need to know where it is defined in the Arduino source code...